# iOS - BLE discovering in the background

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We've got a BLE-device that sends all relevant data in advertisement packets. The device is not an iBeacon, but all relevant data we get without performing a connection.  Logic works in this way: we discover devices and filter them by CBUUID, then get required data from the ManufacturerData dictionary. The device sends data once per second. It works well in the foreground.

The question is: if we can keep a discovering process and data handlings in the Background for a long time?

Comment: You cannot get duplicate discovery events while your app is in the background.

Comment: it's not a duplicate, each sec - new data

Comment: The device itself has already been discovered. Different manufacturer data doesn't count unless you are also changing the MAC each second so that iOS sees it as a different device